# Run a MakeTable query in Access from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have an Excel file that I need to automate.  When the user opens the Excel Report, it will prompt if they would like to refresh the data.  If they say yes, then I need it to run a MakeTable query that is in an Access database to refresh all the underlying numbers for the report.

I have searched and haven't been able to find anything that actually works.

I tried to even create VBA code inside of Access that I could run that would handle the query, but I can't even get that to run from Excel VBA.

Here is the current code I have along with some of what I have tried that didn't work:

```
Sub RunAccessMTQuery(ByVal DBLocation As String)
  Dim db As Object

  Set db = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  With db
    .OpenCurrentDatabase DBLocation
    .Visible = True
'    .Run "Main.RunMTJobBond"
'    .docmd.runmacro "Main.RunMTJobBond"   '<---Module.Proc Name
'    .docmd.runmacro "mMTJobBond"          '<---Macro name that calls the Proc
    .Application.Run "mMTJobBond"
    .CloseCurrentDatabase
    .Quit
  End With

'Below was found on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/131921/running-a-microsoft-access-macro-from-microsoft-excel
'  Dim Chan as Long

'Opens Microsoft Access and the file nwind.mdb
'  Shell("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE"" """ & DBLocation & """")
'Initiates a DDE channel to Microsoft Access
'  Chan = DDEInitiate("MSACCESS", "system")
'Activates Microsoft Access
'  Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftAccess
'Runs the macro 
'  Application.DDEExecute Chan, "RunMTJobBond"
'Terminates the DDE channel
'  Application.DDETerminate Chan

End Sub
```

Either I need to be able to run the MakeTable query from Excel, or launch Access and have it run the query.  Nothing I have tried has worked...I have gotten numerous errors such as:

> Runtime error 5    - Invalid procedure call or arguement
>
> Runtime error 2517 - Application-defined or object-defined error

Others as well, but I don't recall them as I was able to work through those, and these are some of the ones I'm stuck on.  Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `db.Run "mMTJobBond"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application.Run() command runs a function or sub procedure, not a macro.  That's why the attempts to run the macro do not work.

As for running the function or sub directly, the expected parameter format for `Run()` is "*projectname.procedurename*", NOT "modulename.procedurename".  Unless you have multiple VBA projects within your database (which I assume you do not), then you don't even need *projectname*.  See [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193559(v=office.15).aspx).

Try

```
Set dbApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With dbApp
  ...
  .Run "RunMTJobBond"
```

This assume that `RunMTJobBond` is a *public* function or sub in a *standard* module.